# C# client blocking on connection

Tags: c#, c++, pipe

I have C++ code as server and C# code as client.
C# code prints only "1" and "2" then blocked. So I decided that code blocked on connect command.

C++:

```
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
pipe_handle = CreateNamedPipe("\\\\.\\pipe\\pipeName", // pipe name
                              PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |     // read/write access
                              FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,    // overlapped mode
                              PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                              1, // max. instances
                              512, // output buffer size
                              512, // input buffer size
                              20000, // client time-out
                              nullptr); // default security attribute

  if (pipe_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Can't create pipe with error");
    return false;
  }

  SecureZeroMemory(&overlapped, sizeof(overlapped));
  overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, // default security attribute
                                    TRUE,    // manual-reset event
                                    TRUE,    // initial state = signaled
                                    nullptr);// unnamed event object
  if (overlapped.hEvent == nullptr) {
    printf("Can't CreateEvent for pipe with error");
    return false;
  }


if (ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle, &overlapped) || GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
      printf("Can't start named pipe listening");
}
```

C# code:

```
Console.WriteLine("1\n");
var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "pipeName", PipeDirection.InOut);
Console.WriteLine("2\n");
pipeClient.Connect();
if (!pipeClient.IsConnected) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect ....");
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("3\n");
```

Comment: And does the C++ server connect?

Comment: @Charlieface how can I check it?

Comment: You seem to have `printf` logging. Is there any console output?

Comment: @Charlieface for C++ code - no, for C# I have "1" and "2"

Comment: I notice some interesting details. When in C++ code I write to the pipe some bytes of symbols then I can not connect to the pipe. When pipe is empty I can connect. Why do not I connect to not empty pipe?

Comment: I bet the problem is in the name. Compare your code to: https://dev.to/gabbersepp/ipc-between-c-and-c-by-using-named-pipes-4em9

Comment: @BoppityBopbit I have C# as client not as sever